# Multiple columns VS one big-capacity-column?

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance

I have a table like this:

```
// table_A
+--------+---------------+------------+
|   id   |  short-text   | long-text  |
+--------+---------------+------------+
 int(11)    varchar(200)      text         // <= type
```

**Note1:** Always one of `sort-text` or `long-text` is `NULL`. Never both of them aren't containing data. Like this:

```
+--------+---------------+------------+
|   id   |  short-text   | long-text  |
+--------+---------------+------------+
| 1      |some character |  NULL      |
| 2      |some character |  NULL      |
| 3      |some character |  NULL      |
| 4      |some character |  NULL      |
| 5      |some character |  NULL      |
| 6      |NULL           |  some text |
| 7      |some character |  NULL      |
| 8      |some character |  NULL      |
| 9      |some character |  NULL      |
| 10     |some character |  NULL      |
| 11     |some character |  NULL      |
| 12     |NULL           |  some text |
+--------+---------------+------------+
```

**Note2:** As you see in the above table example, always there is 5 rows which `long-text` is `NULL` and then 1 row which `short-text` is `NULL`.

---

Now my question is, that above structure is better or creating just one big capacity column (`type = text`) instead of both those columns? something like this:

```
// table_B
+--------+---------------------+
|   id   | short-and-long-text |
+--------+---------------------+
 int(11)         text                // <= type
```

And here is table containing data:

```
+--------+---------------------+
|   id   | short-and-long-text |
+--------+---------------------+
| 1      | some character      |
| 2      | some character      |
| 3      | some character      |
| 4      | some character      |
| 5      | some character      |
| 6      | some text           |
| 7      | some character      |
| 8      | some character      |
| 9      | some character      |
| 10     | some character      |
| 11     | some character      |
| 12     | some text           |
+--------+---------------------+
```

---

Well, which one is more efficient and optimize? `table_A` or `table_B` ?

**Note3:** I always looking up by ID.

Comment: What kind of queries are going to be run against this table?  If you have to stop and parse the "short-and-long-text" then it won't perform well at all.  Are you searching by the value of the short and long fields or are you always looking up by ID value.

Comment: @JonathanFite I always looking up by ID.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594250/multiple-columns-vs-one-big-capacity-column , which was discussed and, I think, resolved.

Comment: @RickJames Yes that is my question too..! I asked that in SO first and people told me: *(in the comments)*  you have to ask that question in this community, So I asked it here.

Comment: Yeah, they say that -- I can't tell the diff between SO and SE.  (So I troll both.)